# Mesh Hamachi Network - Access server outside of Hamachi but accessible by another client

Tags: vpn, hamachi

Is it possible to access a server or computer that is not on my hamachi network and is accessible from another client PC than the one I am currently using?

Example........
So computer A and Computer B are on Hamachi.
Computer C is not, but computer C is on the same local network as computer B.

I want to VNC (example app, could be something else) to Computer C from computer A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an ssh server on PC B.

PuTTY to it from PC A with an SSH tunnel to PC c.

https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/